# Treating longitudinal data as a repeated cross section

Tags: panel-data, bias, cross-section

Can you introduce bias by treating longitudinal data as a repeated cross section?

Suppose I have two data sources measuring the same variables. The first is a balanced panel dataset $\{y^{long}_{it},X^{long}_{it}\}_{i,t}$ where each individual $i$ is sampled every year $t$. The second is a repeated cross-section $\{y^{cs}_{j},X^{cs}_{j}\}_{j}$ where individual $j$ is only sampled at one point in time $t(j)$.

Will I introduce bias if I treat the panel dataset as a repeated cross section?

To see what I mean, suppose I run two regressions:

$$y^{long}_{it} = X^{long}_{it}\beta + \varepsilon^{}_{it}$$
$$y^{cs}_{j} = X^{cs}_{j}\gamma + \varepsilon^{}_{j}$$

Will $\beta=\gamma$? Or will $\beta$ be biased away from $\gamma$?